# Angularjs converting json data to "[object Object]"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, string, object

i am using Angular resource for ajax calls. I have a update transaction in which i am getting data from the database, while getting data the data is like this:
[image: This is browser console when i am getting data from server]

Now after adding data to empty fields of this object i am again sending it to the server, before sending to the server the data is getting converted into different form like this:
[image]

What can be the possible reason? I have already used JSON.parse(); but it's not working.

**--EDIT--**

This is the code where i am converting sub objects into string

```
            var serverResp = res.data;
            $scope.importLC.main.customerName = serverResp.customerName;
            $scope.importLC.main.customerAddress1 = serverResp.customerAddress1;
            $scope.importLC.main.customerAddress2 = serverResp.customerAddress2;
            $scope.importLC.main.customerAddress3 = serverResp.customerAddress3;
            $scope.importLC.main.issueDate = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'dd-MM-yyyy');

            serverResp = $scope.importLC;

            angular.forEach(serverResp, function (value, key) {
                angular.forEach(serverResp[key], function (v, k) {
                    if (typeof serverResp[key][k] === 'object') {
                        angular.forEach(serverResp[key][k], function (v1, k1) {
                            serverResp[key][k][k1] = String(serverResp[key][k][k1]);
                        });
                    } else {
                        serverResp[key][k] = String(serverResp[key][k]);
                    }
                });
            });

            $scope.importLC = serverResp;
```

I have to convert the values to string but the whole object getting converted into string.

**--EDIT--**

I got the point why the data is converted, actually before sending data to server i am applying validation on data but the validation file only accepts string values so i need to convert the data into string, here is the code

```
        //Convert object to string
        function convertObjectToStringSingleObject(data) {
            Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) {
                data[key] = String(data[key]);
            });
            return data;
        }
```

at the same place i have one more function:

```
    //Convert object to string
    function convertObjectToStringMultiLevelObject(data) {
        Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) {
            Object.keys(data[key]).forEach(function (key1) {
                data[key][key1] = String(data[key][key1]);
            });
        });
        return data;
    }
```

Now if i am using the `convertObjectToStringMultiLevelObject` function then my code is working properly, but some of my other transaction requires `convertObjectToStringSingleObject`. is there any way to combine both the functions (`convertObjectToStringSingleObject` and `convertObjectToStringMultiLevelObject`) and the combined function should be enough intelligent to capture the type of object i mean it can be single level or multi level json object.

Comment: show some relevant javascript

Comment: Converting objects to strings produces `[object Object]`. This can happen for a number of reasons. We'd need to see more code out of you to pinpoint exactly at which point you are converting subobjects to strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some R & D on both of this function i created a combined function which is allowing me to convert object ( object of different levels) values to string, in my case the maximum deep level of object is 2 so the function will looks like:

```
  function convertObjectToString(data) {
        Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) {
            if (data[key] && typeof data[key] === 'object') {
                Object.keys(data[key]).forEach(function (key1) {
                    data[key][key1] = String(data[key][key1]);
                });
            } else if (data[key] && typeof data[key] === 'string' || typeof data[key] === 'number') {
                data[key] = String(data[key]);
            } else {
                data[key] = "";
            }

        });
        return data;
    }
```

I achieved what i wanted because i konw the deep level of my object but i will always welcome a function which will capable to check the deep level and can respond accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While converting object to string use below function

```
var str = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

and while converting from Stringified object to Javascript Object use

```
var obj  = JSON.parse(str);
```

**Edit**

Use `JSON.stringify` if the value is object

```
    function convertObjectToStringSingleObject(data) {
        Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) {
            if (typeof data[key] === "object") {
               data[key] = JSON.stringify(data[key]);
            } else {
               data[key] = String(data[key]);
            }

        });
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: i don't want to convert whole object to string i just want to convert the **values** to string.

Comment: The value you are converting is object that's why it come as "[object object]".

Comment: yes but if i am using `convertObjectToStringMultiLevelObject` function then the code is working fine now my only problem is i want a combined function of `convertObjectToStringMultiLevelObject` and `convertObjectToStringSingleObject` so that my all other transaction also can work perfectly.

Comment: That may be a issue because you may not know how much deep level of object is there

Comment: you need to create recursive function